# Text with different sizes on same line, how to align smaller text horizontally central with bigger text?

Tags: html, css

[image]

As demonstrated in the above image (please take no notice of the fact the Dasboard text is abhorrently large - I only made it that size for this example), I want the text that says "Admin Control Panel" to be aligned horizontally middle with where the Dashboard text is, online with the red arrow.

The code I have for both these pieces of text are:

```
<div id="content-breadcrumb">
  Admin Control Panel &raquo;
    <span id="active">
      Dashboard
    </span>
</div>
```

The CSS code is:

```
#content-breadcrumb {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif
  font-size: 16px;
}

#content-breadcrumb #active {
  font-size: 200px;
  color: #4F95C4;
}
```

Note that I have tried using vertical align and setting line height to no avail. Thanks for any help that you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex box and `align-items` to accomplish this:

(PS: your closing div and span tags are missing the right caret)

```css
#content-breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
  
#active {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-breadcrumb">
  Admin Control Panel &raquo;
    <span id="active">
      Dashboard
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Literally was about to post the same answer. Robert is correct. Flex is the new standard.

Comment: Awkward, they're not in my code! Sure enough, this works. Is there any explanation as to why? I only recently discovered the flexbox after asking a previous question and sure enough the answer was to use the flexbox... but it boggles me! I've looked at a few resources and tutorials but I don't understand how it works. Can you explain? Thank you by the way!

Comment: No problem. Flex Box is a display property (think block, inline-block, etc.), but with much more powerful layout capability.  It's really beyond the scope of stack overflow to explain the inner workings of it, but in what I've provided here  we're simply saying this is display flex, and then with 'align-items' you're defining how elements align the cross axis of the 'flexed' container.  A great resource and learning tool for this is: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use flex-box you can use `vertical-align: middle;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/yrduwpzm/

```css
#content-breadcrumb {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif
  font-size: 16px;
}

#content-breadcrumb #active {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #4F95C4;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

```html
<div id="content-breadcrumb">
  Admin Control Panel &raquo;
    <span id="active">
      Dashboard
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I never understood how `vertical-align: middle` works. Any good resource for the same? :D